# example using beforeMiddleware & webpackBlocker in a karma.config.js file

Tags: karma-runner, webpack-2, es6-modules

i've got a karma-webpack2-qunit setup with babel loader working. es6 is used for both src and test js files.

when running karma in autowatch mode, any changes to source files are detected and karma re-runs the test suite again but the changes are not picked up.

based on this note from the webpack-karma integration page: [webpack-karma middleware info](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack#beforemiddleware) , this seems like the config option i need to get the setup fully working.

***"This loader provides a webpackBlocker middleware that will block tests from running until code recompiles."***

i can't find any examples of using the **webpackBlocker** configuration.

does someone have a working config they can share?

here's what i'm using in karma.config.js:

[image]

the karma test suite is working still but code changes to source or test code do not get reflected in the next run.

Answer (score 0):

i finally got this working. had a mismatch in my "files" pattern config for my test and source files including the "context" object.

[image]

now when i modify either test or source js files, the code is compiled first and the tests are rerun in autowatch mode. yay !!!

will post the full working solution to a GitHub repo in case anybody else wants to get the same "unholy" :-) combination (karma + qunit + webpack + es6 + mocha reporter + phantomjs) working. will also add linting.